# Laravel Middleware Failure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I have a request behind the stock `auth` and `scope` (Passport) middlewares but I'm consistently getting a 301 to the application's login route. Unfortunately it prints literally nothing else to the logs except the 301 response redirecting it to the login route.

I don't have a single clue how I'm supposed to debug middleware and I've been banging my head against the desk trying to search for it. I can put `dd()` in different places in the middleware just to see if it'll fail with something useful, and it'll either print something completely useless to me or it won't have any effect whatsoever.

This uses a resource route scheme that follows the same formatting and is part of the same middleware groups as another route, which works. I'm passing a `POST` request to a `store` method. For the other request, it works fine. So I copy the `Authentication` from the other request to the problematic one, and I'm still getting a `301` response.

---

Going into `\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::authenticate` I see that the guard tripping it up is `\Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard`.

`RequestGuard` uses the trait `GuardHelpers` which provides the `check` method, which just returns whether or not a user is successfully retrieved from the `user` method. The correct user is found. So it seems the guard is okay.

Back in `Authenticate` the next step is to tell `\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager` it `shouldUse` this guard, which entails setting a `userResolver` which just wraps around the `user` method for the guard. After this point I'm not sure where to proceed. It looks like it *should* work, but I'm still getting redirected as if the authentication failed, even though it didn't, according to the internals.

Comment: Paste it here, might not print something completely useless to us? :P

Comment: I've added more details.